# Приложение на сервере не отвечает

Tags: java, развертывание, deploy

Задеплоил java-приложение на linux-сервер от амазон. Jar проекта на сервере есть, java на севере установлена, приложение использует postgres, БД создал вручную. Деплоил и запускал приложение с помощью shell-скрипта:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mvn clean package

echo 'Copy files...'

scp -i ~/.ssh/Albuquerque.pem target/twods-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ubuntu@ec2-18-218-225-76.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/

echo 'Restart server...'

ssh -i ~/.ssh/Albuquerque.pem ubuntu@ec2-18-218-225-76.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com << EOF

pgrep java | xargs kill -9
nohup java -jar twods-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar > log.txt &

EOF

echo 'Bye...'
```

В процессах на сервере приложение запущено на порту 8080. IP сервера - 18.218.225.76

Когда перехожу по 18.218.225.76 страница просто долго грузит и все. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: [I host a website on an EC2 instance. How do I allow my users to connect on HTTP (80) or HTTPS (443)?](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/)

Comment: [Create an EC2 Instance and Install a Web Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html)

Comment: Я создал группу безопасности как тут показано, но это не решило проблему. Вообще этот бесплатный сервер по умолчанию включает такую группу на входящий и исходящий трафик.

Comment: И эта группа разрешает трафик на 80 порту? Вы может не тот адрес смотрите? `IP сервера - 18.188.20.255` .... `Когда перехожу по 18.218.225.76`

Comment: Ой, это я в вопросе изменил только в одном месте. Я остановил и запустил сервер и там ip поменялся. IP - 18.218.225.76, Изначально две группы автоматически создаются, в одной доступ на 22 порту, а другая группа разрешает на всех портах, но я создал на 80 порту тоже группу и добавил ее. Результат не изменился, просто грузит и все

Comment: Пробовали на свой endpoint зайти? `ec2-18-188-20-255.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`? Как вы вообще запустили скрипты на сервере? Через ssh? Как вы поняли, что сервер запущен?

Comment: Я подключился к серверу через ssh в консоли. Еще я установил nginx на сервере и он работает на порту 80, но когда перехожу так же грузит, сообщений от nginx нет никаких. На эндпоинт пробовал заходить, тоже самое

Comment: Если вы подключились к серверу по ssh, то у вас либо 80 порт не открыт, либо ваш софт не настроен как надо. Обратите внимание на ссылки, что я вам дал, там прямо по шагам поясняется настройка доступа. Если же у вас сервер не настроен как надо, тут я уже не помощник.

Comment: Я создал новый сервер линукс один в один по тому туториалу. На 80 порту запускается nginx и когда перехожу, то вижу от него сообщения, но мое приложение как висело так и висит.

Comment: Локально всё работает?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. В общем, для того, чтобы можно было достучаться до приложения, нужно отредактировать группу, которая создается вместе с инстансом, либо сразу при создании инстанса указать в ней общедоступные адреса и порты. Я указал порты 80, 8080, 22(по умолчанию там создается) и все заработало.

Не понятно почему нельзя создать отдельную группу на каждый порт и каждую группу этих правил подключить к одному серверу. Я создавал сначала одну группу на 8080 порт, потом другую группу на 80 порт и подключал эти группы к серверу, но ничего не менялось, доступа к приложению не было. А если создать все эти правила в дефолтной группе, тогда все заработает.